# Injeção de Dependência - Web Api

Tags: c#, aplicação-web, asp.net-web-api, asp

Boa Tarde,

Estou tentando criar a injeção de dependência no Web Api, mas não estou conseguindo, recebo o seguinte erro:

> SimpleInjector.DiagnosticVerificationException
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
>   -[Lifestyle Mismatch] BracoService (Singleton) depends on Banco (Transient).
>   -[Lifestyle Mismatch] CabecaService (Singleton) depends on Banco (Transient).
>   -[Disposable Transient Component] Banco is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.

Global.asax.cs:

```
using BecomexTeste.Service;
using SimpleInjector;
using SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace BecomexTeste
{
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        var container = new Container();

        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();

        container.Register<IBracoService, BracoService>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<ICabecaService, CabecaService>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

        container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        container.Verify(); <----- O ERRO ESTÁ AQUI ----->

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Tente mudar o Lifestyle para Transient, assim `Lifestyle.Transient`

Comment: Ja tentei, mas o erro continua

Comment: O que é esse banco? é seu contexto? acho que tem que registrar ele tbm

Comment: isso é o banco `public class Banco : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Braco> Bracos { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Cabeca> Cabeca { get; set; }
    }`